# Spring JSON Unsupported Media Type

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm trying to send JSON data from Android client to Spring server, but it returns Error Unsupported Media Type.

Android Java request :

```
this.request = new HttpPost(url);    
this.request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
String json = this.gson.toJson(objectEntity);
final StringEntity jsonEntity = new StringEntity(json, JsonEncoding);
jsonEntity.setContentEncoding(JsonEncoding);
this.request.setEntity(jsonEntity);
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.server" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I tried to add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in spring-servlet.xml but now it throws `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread`

jackson version in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

My controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/subscribe", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody SubscriptionResponse subscribe( @RequestBody final  SubscriptionInfo subscribeInfo) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(subscribeInfo.getEmail());
        user.setNickname(subscribeInfo.getNickname());
        user.setPassword(subscribeInfo.getPassword());
        userService.addUser(user);

        User createdUser = userService.findByNickname(subscribeInfo.getNickname());

        SubscriptionResponse subscriptionResponse = new SubscriptionResponse();
        subscriptionResponse.setUserId(createdUser.getId());
        return subscriptionResponse;
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void addUser(User user) {
        userDAO.addUser(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void removeUser(Integer id) {
        userDAO.removeUser(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByNickname(String nickname) {
        return userDAO.findByNickname(nickname);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        return userDAO.findByEmail(email);
    }

}
```

Full stacktrace when remove 'tx:annotation-driven'

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /test/api/user/subscribe: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:168) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:687) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:64) [spring-orm-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:687) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at com.test.server.dao.UserDAOImpl.findByNickname(UserDAOImpl.java:31) [classes:]
    at com.test.server.service.UserServiceImpl.findByNickname(UserServiceImpl.java:28) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198) [spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.findByNickname(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.server.controller.UserController.subscribe(UserController.java:24) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 28 more
```

What I missed?

Comment: I forgot my controller, added in question

Comment: Are you using PUT or POST? Different parameter annotations.

Comment: This is a POST request ( this.request = new HttpPost(url); )

Comment: Try adding "consumes" application/json on your controller's requestmapping. Also, add "produces" application/json

Comment: @ShayElkayam The "produces" is unnecessary (Spring's smart enough to adapt Java objects to JSON with no intervention), but the "consumes" is the key. Add it as an answer if you like.

Comment: I went to sleep 5 minutes after the comment I've made, I saw that you posted it as an answer, +1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED !!!

Added @Transactional in DAO class

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void addUser(User user) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
}
```

spring-servlet.xml :
Renamed sessionFactory bean id, referenced transactionManager id in tx:annotation-driven and 
added mvc:annotation-driven after tx:annotation-driven

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.server" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.onail.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactoryA"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryA" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard POST format is to use form encoding rather than putting the JSON object in the body of the request, and it may be worth simply going with the conventional practice. In addition to being more standard, this more easily supports a future case in which you want to use an HTML form in some frontend interface. In this case, you would simply change the parameter annotation on your controller:

```
SubscriptionResponse subscribe(@ModelAttribute final SubscriptionInfo subscribeInfo)
```

If you really want to keep the model of POSTing an entity body, you need to specifically annotate the method to configure it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/subscribe", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
SubscriptionResponse subscribe(@RequestBody final SubscriptionInfo subscribeInfo)
```

Comment: I added consumes = "application/json" still don't work..
I think this is due to the absence of <mvc:annotation-driven /> in spring-servlet.xml but how to add it without breaking hibernate ?

Comment: @alvinm93 You have `tx:annotation-driven` in your XML config, but I don't seen `@Transactional` applied anywhere.

Comment: I tried to comment all database call in my controller and in spring-servlet.xml to comment `<tx:annotation-driven />` and add `<mvc:annotation-driven />`, now JSON IN/OUT working perfectly ! But i want to communicate with a database.. how to use hibernate without obtaining `Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here`

EDIT : Added my service in first post, there is @Transactional

Comment: @alvinm93 At the very least, post that stack trace.

Comment: Added stacktrace in first post

Comment: @alvinm93 Out of curiosity, why does your class copy the repository interface instead of just using it in your main code?

Comment: I dont know.. i used this tutorial http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/